# Why code doesn't work in layouts?

Tags: layout, yii

I have this code:

```
<a itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject"> <?= Html::img("@web/images/$game->Photo", ['alt' => 'Description', 'title' => 'Description']) ?>
```

It works perfectly on page `site.com/www/views/game/`, but it doesn't work on page `site.com/www/views/layouts/`, and I don't know why.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

could be related to the fatct that in layout the  $model  (in  your case $game) is not available

you could change your controller/action  in the way  adding your model to the param

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
   .....
   $this->view->params['game'] = $game;
   .....
   $this->render(...); 

}
```

and then for  accessing game  in layout you should retrieve using

```
$game = $this->params['game'];
```